# UML to Java code - Multiplicity Indicator and capitalized variable

Tags: java, uml, diagram

I am learning UML and I need to transform a given UML diagram to java code. I already created the Manager class, the Account class and the Ident interface.

I marked the parts that i do not understand yet in yellow. Concerning the Account class i do not understand what AccountCounts is. I thought it could be a private static int  instance variable, but it makes no sense that it is written with an uppercase letter at the beginning then. 
So i thought it is an inner class, but this does not make sense neither.

I also do not know if it is possible to represent the multiplicity in code. I get the idea that 1 Manager Object can use multiple Objects of the type Account. But i am not sure how 1 Manager Object can work with Ident Objects, since this is an interface. I can't even create an instance of an Interface, can i?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid the answer to your question is "buy a UML book or follow a course". UML is a language. You can't just swing it, you have to actually learn it to understand.

Comment: ``List<Ident>`` means a list of objects that implement interface ``Ident``, for example instances of ``Account``. The list may refer to a mix of instances of various classes, as long as all these classes implement ``Ident``.

Comment: thanks for the replies! I am reading books and following a course already, but as it is the case with every language you do not undertand all of its details immediatly. Since I have not found the two described cases in my studying material yet I decided to ask to get a hint. 
thanks www.admiraalit.nl, now this makes it clearer how I have to interpret the List<Ident> variable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Geert said. Anyhow:

- Ask the author of the UML why he capitalized `AccountCounts`. As you assumed it's a static local attribute.
- Multiplicity can be expressed in many ways. If you have low multiplicities you can instantiate a `var1`, `var2`, etc. Or you use lists as you did.
- The names you marked are names of the association (which I never found very useful for my modeling). They probably should be role names but they aren't. If so they need to be near the far end (here to the right) and have a visibility indicator (`+`+, `-`, etc.) in front.

Comment: thanks qwerty_so! Then I will go for the solution to implement AccountCounts as a private static int variable.

Answer (score 0):

**Multiplicities or Cardinalities**

- 1 to 0..n means that 1 manager can have zero or many accounts (same with the other association relationship as well).

**Labels on Association lines**

- The labels on the line indicate the nature of the interaction of one class with the other. In most cases, it is recommended to use a verb on the line as a label.(eg:'accounts' on the association relationship from Manager to Account)

**AccountCounts**

- The reason 'AccountCounts' in the Account class is underlined is because it is treated as a variable and not as an attribute. From my experience with converting UML class diagrams to code, I believe you need to store the number of Account instances created in the 'AccontCounts' variable. But it is advisable to read your case study and understand what is required.

*Please use these resources to help you understand OOP and UML diagrams better*
**Sage (2019). Concise Guide to Object-Oriented Programming**